# Does JMS QueueBrowser getEnumeration requires Connection Start

Tags: java, jms

I want to know if its required to call JMS Connection start() before we do QueueBrowser browse(). Could not find anything in javadoc about start() as a pre-op to browse() and each vendor samples for browse seems to be different. Some of them calls while other’s don’t.
I ask this as ActiveMQ does not browse messages if I don’t perform start().

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://**:**");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();

connection.start();

Session session = connection.createSession(false, 1);
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
message.setText("This is a sample message");

Queue dest = new ActiveMQQueue("Sample");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(dest);
producer.send(message);

QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(dest);
Enumeration<Message> messages = browser.getEnumeration();
/* Iteration code here 
 * If connection.start() is'nt called, no element in returned collection
 * If connection.start() is called, the returned collection contains 
 * queue elements.
 */
..
```

Could not find java doc talking anything specific to start before peek on the queue. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Connection.Start()` is required. `QueueBrowser` is similar to `MessageConsumer` with only difference being `QueueBrowser` does not remove message from JMS provider. Without application calling `Connection.Start` method JMS provider will not deliver messages.

Comment: Thanks :). I was curious to know if there is anything that JMS talks about calling start only for message delivery. Isn't browsing a queue different than receiving (where the sole purpose is message delivery)